# The update of CRUD service not working with not constructor exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got `TypeError: this.service is not a constructor`

When I tried to click save button , it will trigger `$scope.updateBank`, then `Bank.prototype.update` method

[image: inline]

## update function in controller

```
$scope.updateBank = $scope.BankService.update;
```

## Create Bank CRUD service

> I also tried .service, it still not works.

```
angular.module('bank', [])
    .factory('bankService', function($resource, $http) { // I also tried .service, it still not works.
        var Bank;
        return Bank = (function() {
            function Bank(BankListId, errorHandler) {
                var defaults;
                // http://dev.co
                this.service = $resource('/api/v1/banks/:id', {
                    id: '@id'
                }, {
                    update: {
                        method: 'PUT'
                    }
                });
                this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
            }

        Bank.prototype.update = function(bank, bank_id) {
            console.log(bank) // Object {name: "Simonis Inc!!"}
            console.log(bank_id) // 101
            return new this.service({
                Bank: bank
            }).$update({
                id: bank_id
            }, (function() {
                return null;
            }), this.errorHandler);
        };

        // the query all function works perfectly.

        Bank.prototype.all = function() {
            return this.service.query((function() {
                return null;
            }), this.errorHandler).$promise;
        };
```

## Update

### banks_controller

```
$q.all([this.BankService.all().$promise]).then(function(ret){
  $scope.banks = ret[0]
  console.log($scope.banks)
});

$scope.updateBank = this.BankService.update;
```

### REST service

```
        Bank.prototype.update = function(bank, bank_id) {
            # here, `this` is the banks_controller
        };

        // the query all function works perfectly.

        Bank.prototype.all = function() {
            # `this` is the Bank
        };
```

Comment: try: `bank.service` instead of `new this.service`

Comment: @NishanthMatha Thank you , However, I got `TypeError: this.service is not a function`. pls take a look on update, the query all function works, but the update doesn't work

Comment: gotcha.. try `this.service.save`

Comment: @NishanthMatha `angular.js:12477 TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined` LoL `return this.service.save({....`

Comment: intresting if that's a valid `resource` you should have `save` or `$save` method. You best bet is to do `console.log(this.service)` and see what methods it has

Comment: @NishanthMatha I found the buggy point, would you please give me some hint?

Comment: @NishanthMatha thank you , pls take a look on `REST service` section. one is in Bank object , the other (the buggy one) is in bank_controller scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error lies here :

```
$scope.updateBank = this.BankService.update;
```

NEVER bind a method (= with a this) to another object or the 'this' will be undefined or pointing to another object (like the $scope).

```
$scope.updateBank = function(){
    this.bankService.update();
}
```

Comment: You saved me, thanks. I fixed by this way    ` $scope.updateBank = function(bank, id){
      new bankService().update(bank, id)
    }`

Comment: you shouldn't need to use  `new` but get the service injected by Angular